# Segfault with using ccall in Julia when `GC.enable(true)`

Tags: c, shared-libraries, julia

I'm having a odd issue where I am interfacing with a shared library and I get segfaults when I try to use `ccall`. I've rewritten my code in Python, but do not get any issues. It also only occurs when `GC.enable(true)`. If I run `GC.enable(false)` before I run any `ccall` function, everything works fine.

Oddly enough, when I run the following:

```
GC.enable(false)
var1 = Ref(...)
var2 = pointer(...)
ccall(...)
GC.enable(true)
```

it still segfaults.

I have a minimal working example posted in this [GitHub link](https://github.com/kdheepak/opendss-debug) over here. I'm hoping someone can take a look at it and tell me what I'm doing incorrectly?

Additionally, if can someone can offer suggestions on what the best practices are when using ccall in Julia when working with different kinds of patterns in C, that would be extremely useful. At the moment, the most information I've found is the official documentation, which is useful but doesn't cover all the patterns I've seen when interfacing with C code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could use `GC.@preserve` to temporarily preserve variables from being garbage collected:

```
var1
var2

GC.@preserve var1 var2 begin
    ccall(...)
    var3 = unsafe_xxx
end

var3
```

the real reason is that your shared lib needs `ResultPtr` to be correctly initialized and you were just hitting some undefined behaviors:

#### REPL

```
julia> Ref{Ptr{Cstring}}(C_NULL)
Base.RefValue{Ptr{Cstring}}(Ptr{Cstring} @0x0000000000000000)

julia> Ref{Ptr{Cstring}}()
Base.RefValue{Ptr{Cstring}}(Ptr{Cstring} @0x000000011b98ca70)  # this results in segfaults
```

#### CMD

```
➜  opendss-debug git:(master) ✗ julia -e '@show Ref{Ptr{Cstring}}()'
Ref{Ptr{Cstring}}() = Base.RefValue{Ptr{Cstring}}(Ptr{Cstring} @0x0000000000000000)
```

Comment: I still seem to be getting a segfault. I believe the issue is that the shared library code is trying to free the memory when it's not supposed to (???). In Julia, when I use `ResultPtr = Ref{Ptr{Cstring}}()`, do you know if this allocates memory on the heap? Can the shared library modify this memory?

Comment: It looks like your lib needs `Ref{Ptr{Cstring}}(C_NULL)` to be correctly initialized.

Comment: Thanks! That seemed to have solved it. Do you know why it works with both `Ref{Ptr{Cstring}}(C_NULL)` and `Ref{Ptr{Cstring}([])`? I wrote an equivalent C code (uploaded to the same git repo) for the shared library (original shared library code was in Pascal) and managed to figure out that it works with both cases.

Comment: My understanding is `char ***` can be interpreted either as a pointer to an array of Cstrings(`C_NULL` is a nullptr) or an array of pointers which are of type `Ptr{Cstring}`(`Ptr{Cstring}[]` is an empty array). Anyway, the content of `ResultPtr` will be populated by C, so there is no difference how you init it.